# querying users from table if user.id is found in another table

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I am using flask with sqlAlchemy to connect with a postgresql database with two tables

`Users table (id, name)`

`Admissions table (id, userId)`

`Admissions table` with a `foreign key (userId)` connected to `Users(id)`

I want to get `Users` if `user.id` is found in `admissions` `userId`

This is what I am doing

```
users = [i for i in Users.query.all() if Admissions.query.filter_by(userid=i.id).first()]
```

Any better way to do this?

Thank you

Edit:
`Users`

```
Table "public.users"
  Column  |         Type          | Collation | Nullable |              Default               
----------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------
 id       | integer               |           | not null | nextval('users__id_seq'::regclass)
 sid      | character varying(10) |           |          | 
 name     | text                  |           |          | 
 username | text                  |           |          | 
 password | text                  |           |          | 
 admin    | boolean               |           |          | false
 deleted  | boolean               |           |          | false
Indexes:
    "users_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "admissions" CONSTRAINT "admissions_userid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES users(id)
```

`Admissions`

```
Table "public.admissions"
   Column   |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                Default                 
------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------
 id         | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('admissions_id_seq'::regclass)
 examid     | integer                  |           |          | 
 userid     | integer                  |           |          | 
 startdate  | timestamp with time zone |           |          | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 submitdate | timestamp with time zone |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "admissions_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "admissions_userid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES users(id)
```

Comment: Could you please add the SQL for the definitions of all 3 tables.

Comment: @pacmaninbw done